# Passing parameters to corb uri stage using ml-gradle

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle, marklogic-corb

I'm using ml-gradle with corb2 2.4.5 and Marklogic 9.0.5.

I'm trying to pass a parameter to corb when running the gradle task.  I've passed the parameter in at

`-DURIS-MODULE.id="sf"`

In my xquery module, I have

`declare variable $id as xs:string external;`

The corb process runs, but it doesn't set the id variable.  What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: That looks correct. Can you update and add the complete command launching? Just a guess, maybe the system property is being set after the manager class instead of before? https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/Running-CoRB#usage-4---combination-of-properties-file-with-java-system-properties-and-command-line-options

Comment: I'm using gradle, not Java directly from the command-line, so the class order isn't an issue.  

If nobody can help, I'll fall back on the Java command-line invocation

Comment: What version of ml-gradle are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All system properties should be set and passed to your CoRB job when executing the ml-gradle CoRB task.

I suspect that you might be running an old version of ml-gradle, or there may be something else that is off in your job.

I have verified that I can pass in an external URIS-MODULE variable to this simplified job by executing the following command:

```
gradle -DURIS-MODULE.id=2 -DURIS-MODULE="INLINE-XQUERY|declare variable $id external;concat('PROCESS-MODULE.id=',string($id)),1,1|ADHOC" -DPROCESS-MODULE="INLINE-XQUERY|declare variable $id external;xdmp:log(concat('process module id=',$id))|ADHOC" corb
```

and I see that my application servers error log includes the line:

```
2020-03-12 09:23:44.198 Info: process module id=2
```

The ml-gradle CoRB task collects all system properties and passes them to CoRB when the task runs:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/marklogic/gradle/task/CorbTask.groovy#L102

```
Map options = buildCorbOptions()
//CoRB2 will evaluate System properties for options
systemProperties(options)

super.exec()
```

The `buildCorbOptions()` method 
https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/marklogic/gradle/task/CorbTask.groovy#L121

```
  /**
  * Construct CoRB2 options from the following sources:
  * task variables - lowerCamelCase names that correspond to their CoRB2
  *                  option (i.e. optionsFile => OPTIONS-FILE)
  * project properties - Project properties with the naming convention
  *                      of a 'corb' prefix and CamelCased CoRB2 option name
  *                      (i.e. corbOptionsFile => OPTIONS-FILE)
  * System properties - Any System property with a CoRB2 option name
  *
  * If properties are defined in more than one place, System properties will take
  * precedence over Project properties, which take precedence over task member variables.
  *
  * @return Map of CoRB2 options
  */
  public Map buildCorbOptions() {
    //first, convert legacy task properties and generate options from conventions
    Map options = collectNormalizedOptions()
    //collect all of the corb task options (i.e. threadCount=12)
    options << collectMemberVariables()
    //apply any corb project properties (i.e. -PcorbThreadCount=12)
    options << collectCorbProjectProperties()
    //apply any CoRB2 System properties (i.e. -DTHREAD-COUNT=12)
    options << collectSystemProperties()
    options //return the merged options
  }
```

invokes the `collectSystemProperties()` method:

```
  /**
  * Collect all System.properties. This allows for any CoRB option to be set, including those not statically known such
  * as CoRB custom inputs (e.g. URIS-MODULE.foo, PROCESS-MODULE.bar, etc) as well as settings for other libraries, such
  * as xcc.httpCompliant to enable XCCS compatability for XCC.
  * @return all System.properties
  */
  public Map collectSystemProperties() {
    System.properties
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; that's the best overview I've seen anywhere of using ml-gradle with corb.

I updated to the latest ml-gradle and tweaked my code a bit; between the two of them, that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the type `CorbTask`, not a Java task, to take advantage of the parameter processing.

Use:

```
task some-corbCorbTask(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.CorbTask) {...}
```

rather than:

```
task some-corbJAVA(type: Java) {...}
```